# Simplify Dictionary with For Loop Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, dictionary, xaml, variables, xamarin

I'm trying to simplify the creation of this dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<Guid, int> emojiSelect = new Dictionary<Guid, int>
            {

                { emoji0.Id, 0 },
                { emoji1.Id, 1 },
                { emoji2.Id, 2 },
                { emoji3.Id, 3 },
                { emoji4.Id, 4 },
                { emoji5.Id, 5 },
                { emoji6.Id, 6 },
                { emoji7.Id, 7 },

            };
```

Using a FOR loop because the elements follow an incrementing structure and it would reduce the size of the application, in turn saving users space. But because the key of the dictionary is populated with a Guid of a XAML element, I have hit an impasse where I don't know how to use a string to reference a variable name.

I have started with this:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter <= 7; counter++)
            {
                emojiArray.Add(//???\\, counter);
            }
```

I would essentially like to be able to concat the word "emoji" with the number currently stored in the 'counter' variable and use that as a reference to the specific XAML element as currently happens in the fully written dictionary like this:

```
EG: "emoji" ++ 1 --> reference to 'emoji1' object
```

After this reference is made, I will be able to use .Id on the end of it to recover it's Guid

Comment: and what is `emojiN` ? Obviously if it's some field you can do it only via reflection (which was already answered in similar questions)

Comment: what does the XAML look like?  Is the GUID hardcoded?  I'm not sure the effort to solve this is really worth the minor change it will make to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **emoji**s are `Element`s in **Xaml**, you could get them by loop its RootLayout.

For example, if them are in **StackLayout** as follows:

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="RootLayout">
     ...
     <... x:Name="emoji0" .../>
     <... x:Name="emoji1".../>
     <... x:Name="emoji2".../>
     ...
 </StackLayout>
```

Then you can get them as follows:

```
foreach (var item in RootLayout.Children)
{
    emojiArray.Add(item.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++" +item.Id);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you! Would you say that this method or just defining the dictionary as I have already done would be more efficient?

Comment: @MatthewSwallow Obviously, this method is more efficient if you're not going to be changing the contents. In addition, this method will be more flexable no matte how much child elements exist.

Comment: Thank you again! Yes this will be a static dictionary and so I'll implement this!